# How to determine the cpu, disk, and ram for my production mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb, deployment

I plan to deploy 2 shards and 3 config servers. each shard has 3 members.

Assume that the raw data is X.

1, What is the disk size I need considering indexes, log files, Preallocated data files, and journal? 
Each member in the shard has the same copy of data. So, the disk for data should be at least 3X. but consider indexes, journal, log files, and so on, the size should be much more than 3X.

2, What is the size for RAM?

3, How about CPUs?

Are there good docs on the internet? I did not find them.

Comment: Proper capacity planning involves much more detail than "my raw data is X". You need to test & understand how your application & infrastructure will scale. For example, how much of your raw data do you need to access on a regular basis and how large are the indexes (aka your ["working set"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/#what-is-working-set-and-how-can-i-estimate-its-size)). As a starting point for considerations, I would suggest the [MongoDB webinar on capacity planning](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/webinar-capacity-planning).

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find more details about the application. But I found that the file size is about 2 times the data size on each data server. So, I plan to use disk with at least 6X. I also plan to use 10% * 6X as the RAM size. In the future, I can get more details about the application metrics or when the performance is limited. Then I can add shard or improve the hardware, such as RAM.

Comment: I don't think your metrics are useful aside from guesstimating storage size might be 2X data size (that actually seems excessive). As noted, capacity planning really depends on your use case. If you need to work with 100% of the data then you need enough RAM to cover this (or fast storage to compensate for frequent page faulting); if your working set is 10% of the data you won't need to provision as much RAM. A write heavy workload will be different from a read heavy workload. Instead of guessing percentages and multipliers, I would test in a representative environment. There is no formula.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your suggestions